# Would WCF client work over USB in compact framework?

Tags: wcf, compact-framework, usb

Would WCF work through normal USB connection or does it require WIFI when using the Mobile Device as a WCF client to a WCF service running on the PC?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean over usb via activesync, or just over USB in general?

I have consumed RESTFul WCF services on WM6 devices over usb/activesync. The activesync connection gives you a network connection that supports TCP. Use the host name 'ppp_peer' if you want to address the host pc you are connected to.

Comment: "ppp_peer" only works if you are not using ActiveSync's "advanced" networking mode, which is the default in recent versions of ActiveSync. "dtpt_peer" is the more current version of this special hostname.

Comment: ppp_peer works fine for me over mobile device center, using wm6.5 emu with the advanced network functionality checked. Also works for my wm6.1 device.

But thanks for the info, it makes more sense to use desktop passthru rather than ppp :)

Answer (score 0):

I use ActiveSync and resolve the hostname "dtpt_peer" which maps to 169.254.2.2, the IP assigned by the CF device to the desktop peer, and then use WCF via TCP.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that it wouldn't work over the USB connection because the USB is not a network connection.  Unless you are referring to some kind of USB ethernet adapter, and not a USB cable plugged directly from your mobile to your computer, then you are most likely out of luck in this regard.

Comment: Incorrect.  The USB connection *is* a network connection.  It's an RNDIS connection in recent versions, in older versions it was a seudo network, but port 80 still worked just fine.